# How to upload more than 100 files at once in github?

Tags: github

I want to add a folder that has 713 files 150 folders inside it.

Uploading directly shows an error that I cannot upload more than 100 files at once.

Is there any chance I could upload a .rar file and then later extract in github?

[image]

Comment: Are you actually using `git`? Because I don't think commits with more then 100 changes are blocked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to send an archived file and extract it in GitHub. However, Like  [Fake Name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268006/fake-name) said, you need to download Git on your system and use it to send your files to `GitHub`. You can go through the tutorials on Git [here](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can't upload more than 100 files using the Graphic Interface.

You can instead upload a .rar instead as you said, but it's not recommended. When you will try to update the repository you will find that you will re-upload all the .rar.

So what I recommend you to do is upload using the terminal (using terminal you can upload more than 100 files).
And for information on how you upload on GitHub using terminal, follow those steps:
https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line