# how can I upload a file bigger than 100 files to github

Tags: css, file, github, upload, large-files

how can I upload a file bigger than 100files(1437 files) to Github.
I can't upload more than 100 files. most of the files are coming from node_modules. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload more than 100 files at once in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404202/how-to-upload-more-than-100-files-at-once-in-github)

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to commit node_modules folder, instead include that in `.gitignore` file.